# Why did Talbot have so much more control?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

When

> Ruby was infused with a mere fraction of the gravitonium,

they had virtually no control over their powers. They killed their romantic interest, even though they clearly didn’t want to, and their powers caused all sorts of movement. On the other hand, their *personality* experienced relatively little change — they still had the same desires; they just had issues with the voices.

By contrast, when

> Talbot

was infused with a much greater quantity, their personality *did* change dramatically, and they certainly used their powers to hurt people, but they immediately seemed to have much more control. They didn’t kill people upon touching them when they didn’t want to, for example.

What accounts for the much greater control?

Comment: He's older, and has more experience with leading people, and fighting wars.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Plausible, and Talbot kind of suggested some similar - but he was also clearly wrong about not being affected, so....

Comment: The control issues are from the voices shouting, how much chance do you think a voice in Talbot's head has of shouting him down?  The man is not a listener.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are multiple differences between Ruby and Talbot.

Ruby is a troubled teenager seeking approval from her mother, and recklessly tries to gain that approval by infusing herself with the gravitonium. Her boyfriend prematurely (althought that didn't seem to make much difference) aborts the sequence because of her agony.
She finds herself with these two grown men shouting in her head and with powers she doesn't fully understand yet.

Talbot on the other hand has had head trauma for quite some time, has been brainwashed over and over and is probably much stronger mentally. Even though they broke him eventually. That and the fact that he is a leader, a soldier who would't take order from some puny civilians (who happen to be in his head) made him more in control I think. The only reason he became "evil", isn't the gravitonium or it's effects, but the pre-existing head trauma, causing him to be paranoid. which he already was when Caulson saved him.

Comment: He has a line, something like "they needed a general to keep them in line", referring to the voices.